# What are the options for cooling a metal-bodied laptop?

Tags: cpu, macbook, macbook-pro, cooling

The CPU temperature of my 2014 MBP for years has routinely been in the high 90s C. What are the ways to cool it? (I'm trying to avoid throttling, which causes programs I'm using to slow down.) Ones I've tried are:

- Fan-based cooling pad
- Cleaning dust out of inside
- Removing thermal paste, applying AS5
- Putting on top of big rectangular ice pack

Answer (score 1):

Below is a list of several common causes and contra-measures.
If none of them applies and the temperature causes problems when running the
computer, it might need a repairman or hardware upgrades.

- A temperature in the 90s C may not mean overheating, unless you are experiencing
  thermal throttling.
- The operating system should be fully patched, since power handling bugs
  may have been found and fixed.
- To see which apps are using the most CPU resources, open Activity Monitor and
  click on the CPU tab to see which applications are at or near the top of the list.
- Keep the number of tabs in the browser to a reasonable minimum.
  Web-pages with Flash ads are to be avoided.
- If your Mac struggles to juggle multiple apps, lessen its load by closing apps
  you aren't using, instead of leaving them running in the background.
- SMC, short for System Management Controller, is a chip in your Mac that
  runs many physical parts of the machine including the cooling fans.
  An SMC reset is harmless and is done this way:

  - Shut down and plugin the power adapter, putting the Mac in charge mode
  - Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>
    and press the power button at the same time for a few seconds
  - Release the keys and turn on the Mac.
- Use an original MacBook Charger. If you have bought a generic replacement,
  it might not work well and cause overheating and other issues.
- Check if the applications you are using are too heavy for the hardware
  as regarding memory and CPU, causing swaps and overwork.
- Note: Using fan control software is a bad idea.